GA4 doesn't providing the number of click on specific button
Few days ago I have added gTag manager to one of my project and added a code to track number of click that button received. So I have 4 categories button and each named as alpha, beta, gamma, theta.
function trackCategoryClick(category) {
        gtag('event', 'click', {
            'event_category': 'Book Button',
            'event_label': category,
        });
}

This is the code. So here the category variable holds the name alpha, beta, gamma and theta.
when I check in google Analytics 4

Go to Reports
Go to Business Objective
Go to examine user behaviour
Then go to Events

Under Events, I can see Number of list under Event Name column such as

Page_view
click
Scroll
User_engagement
Session_start
First_visit

I chose Click and I can see that how many times user has clicked on alpha, beta and other button in the right box. But it says that data is for last 30 mins. I need to see the same thing for a month. How many times alpha, beta and other button has been clicked in a month period of time.

You will need to create custom parameters in order to see the parameters in explorer reports (as well as Looker reports).
To do this, you will need to go in to Admin >> Custom Definitions. From here, you will need to create custom dimensions for each of the parameters you are passing (excluding the event name):

Click the "Create custom definition" button
Enter a unique dimension name as this is what it will appear as in your reports.
Choose a scope. This will likely be event and not user since it is occurring when clicks happen.
Enter a brief description in case someone else is looking at your property.
Choose the appropriate event parameter from the dropdown. This will be based off of the scope previously selected. It will only show the appropriate parameters for each scope.
Click "Save" button.

They say that parameters will take 48 hours until you can start using them in your reports. You will need to do this for all new parameters you want to use in your reports. This should be your process when you start logging new events and parameters.
